# Sort by painless script with missing values

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I am trying to write a sort script which sorts by a value which might be messing:

1. doc1: `{ id: 1, inner: { state: "active" }}`
2. doc2: `{ id: 2, inner: { state: "inactive" }}`
3. doc3: `{ id: 3 }`

I am trying to sort by `inner.state` OR empty inner value.

Naively I tried:

`doc['inner.state'].value != 'inactive' ? 0 : 1`

Which works, but ignores the `doc3`.

Basically I need something like:

`!exists(doc['inner']) || doc['inner.state'].value != 'inactive' ? 0 : 1`

I also tried things like:

`doc['inner'].empty ? 1 : 0`

which results in `{"type":"script_exception","reason":"runtime error"}`

Comment: What is inner and sale here?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

Next time, you can consider attaching the full error (at least in version 7.12's DEV Tools) I am getting exact errors (including script stack) and even a "caused_by" attribute, that contains the reason why a given script is failing.

So, here comes my answer:
Provided `inner.state` is a keyword (or in general a sortable field) you can write as follows:

```java
if(doc['inner.state'].empty) { 
   return 0; 
} else { 
   return doc['inner.state'].value != 'inactive' ? 0.5 : 1 
}
```

Note I forced an order between empty field and inactive state.

### Full Reproducible Example

Create index with suitable mapping:

```json
PUT test/
{"mappings":{"properties":{"inner":{"properties":{"state":{"type":"keyword"}}}}}}
```

Index the data:

```json
POST _bulk
{"index": { "_index": "test", "_id": 1}}
{"inner": {"state": "active"}}
{"index": { "_index": "test", "_id": 2}}
{"inner": {"state": "inactive"}}
{"index": { "_index": "test", "_id": 3}}
{"another_field": "test"}
```

Retrieve the result sorted according to the definition:

```json
GET test/_search
{
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "number",
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": "if(doc['inner.state'].empty) { return 0 } else { return doc['inner.state'].value != 'inactive' ? 0.5 : 1 }"
      },
      "order": "asc"
    }}
}
```